# In Jquery, how can I select only the first parent of an element

Tags: jquery, html

I have this structure:

```
<input placeholder="Filter by name" id="filterBox" type="text" />
<ul class="navList">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>

<ul>
```

And I want to select only the first parent.
For exemple select this: `<li><a>3</a></li>` when I click the `<a>3</a>`

I tried `.parent()`, `.closest('li')` but it keeps selecting all my li list.

```
$('#filterBox').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.navList>li>a').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).parent().show() : $(this).parent().hide();            
    });
});
```

This is the working JSFiddle after problem resolution, thanks: http://jsfiddle.net/ybugdb57/

Comment: Post the full JavaScript code you're using. Both .parent() and .closest() should work, but it depends on how you're using them.

Comment: Show us your JS code.  You're asking a JS question afterall...

Comment: JSfiddle URL please.

Comment: What you've posted works: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kcz3qh8u/. Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: It works now.. Thank you j08691. I just had to restarted my browser.. some kind of weird bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get its immediate parent use

```
$('#element').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `click` event handler, you can write something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var myParent = $(this).parent();
    /* ... other code ... */
});
```

See an example in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24wxw3L1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's `$(selector).parent()`; That's it. Problem is, you're not using it correctly in your context - meaning you don't know how to target the element being clicked on - that's the **this** selector. It should probably be something along the lies of:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e){
   $(this).parent();
});
```

Comment: OP is using `$(this).parent()`.

Comment: @j08691 When i posted the reply, he had not posted his JS code. You could have deducted that from the comments to his post (the ones asking for the JS code).

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).parent());
});

$('a').click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).closest('li'));
});
```